# For voice tasks in Twilio Flex, how do I get the current conference ConferenceSid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I can see that for all the voice interactions, behind the scenes flex is using its voice API to create a conference between caller and worker. How do I obtain the created ConferenceSid after the task has been selected and reserved?

What I would like to do is simply Get the value upon connecting.

I can see a very long and not so pretty way of getting it, which is by running a twilio function that iterates over every conference, making additional requests to see the participants. But that seems way to complex to me. 
I can see in the logs that the conference friendly is being printed

```
ConferencesState handleConferenceUpdate WT5d0800a3ce8724fd55cf89841c48XXX
```

Is there anyone who can help here?

UPDATE:
@philnash below answered the question exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There seems like a couple of ways to get hold of the Conference SID in a Flex interaction.

First, the task that your worker accepts [has a number of attributes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/tasks#task-attributes) that are set by Flex and relevant for the type of task it is. For a voice call, you will find a `conference` key, which has an object including the `sid` as well as entries for the participants.

Secondly, I found that the `<TaskCanvas>` component in the UI is passed a context that includes a `conference` object. That object then has a `source` property which expands to an object with a `conferenceSid` property, as well as other properties, including a `participants` list.

Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you a ton. Worked like a charm.